# Deep Copy object

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1, observablecollection

I want to deep copy a collection (which contains complex objects and other collections) on windows phone 8.1 platform. What is the best solution for this?

NOTE: i read that the "easiest" (shortest) way is something like this:

```
List<MyClass> copiedObject = 
  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(
      JsonConvert.SerializeObject(originalObject)
   );
```

But if I use this my ObservableCollections won't work anymore, so if I bind the copied collection to an UI element it won't be updated after I change something in the collection.

So my "side-question" is: why my collections goes "corrupted"?

Binding:

```
<Pivot.ItemTemplate> 
   <DataTemplate> 
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EventList}"/> 
   </DataTemplate>
</Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: How do you bind it to the UI, and what does "ObservableCollections won't work anymore" mean? What kind of behavior do you expect?

Comment: In addition to @AntonSizikov's question: what do you expect to happen when you have 2 clones of the object in relation to binding?

Comment: My binding:
[...]
<Pivot.ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EventList}">
  [...]
where EventList is an ObservableCollection containing Events and part of a class named PageContext.
If I remove an event from EventList it is removed from the ListView. I want to create a copy of EventList
because I need to restore it later. Now, if I copy the original EventList into a new collection, and later
I copy (with JSON.net Serialize/Deserialize) it back into the original one (which is binded to the ListView) and then I modify an event, nothing 
happens with the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class which contains the EventList property should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.100).aspx) interface.

```
public class PageContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private ObservableCollection _eventList;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection EventList
    {
        get { return _eventList; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_eventList)) return;
            _eventList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EventList");
        }
    }
}
```

When you bind first time the ui control will store the reference to the collection and will observe it for the new changed. After that you create a new collection and assign it to EventList property, but you do not notify the ui control that collection has changed.

Another option is not to create a new `ObservableCollection`, but to empty an existing one and add every element from the copy one by one.

Comment: Adding OnPropertyChanged to the ObservableColletion itself worked like a charm, thank you very much!